# fullcalendar change size line of hours

Tags: javascript, html, css, fullcalendar

[image]

This is my calendar. I want to make the line of hours more bigger same like this calendar:

[image]

I want the user to know how to make a difference between the hour line and the other lines.

I try with this but it makes all lines bigger

```
fc .fc-timegrid-slot {
     height: 18px;
     border-bottom: solid;
 }
```

[image]

Comment: Inspecting the DOM of the Resource Time Grid (I think that is what your screenshot is showing?) example here https://fullcalendar.io/demos, you can quickly discover that the table cells for the non full-hour slots have the additional class `fc-timegrid-slot-minor` ...

Comment: P.s., please go read https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting